# How to use Backbone view with a jquery accordion?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js

I am creating a jquery accordion on my page. The different tabs of the accordion contain forms for different attributes of a larger composite object. I want to populate each tab of the accordion using its own Backbone view. The problem is that each view can only be bound to a single `DOM` element only whereas an accordion requires me to declare two elements for each tab.

Is there a workaround to this in either jQuery accordion or backbone? I'll gladly change my HTML (though not the design) to have separate views for each sub-form.

One alternative that I have thought of is to declare 2 views for each tab - one for the tab header and one for the tab body. This, though, unnecessarily doubles the no. of views.

Another alternative is to do something like described in [How to set nothing on el or tagname to work with jquery ui accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809771/how-to-set-nothing-on-el-or-tagname-to-work-with-jquery-ui-accordion?rq=1)

Comment: I think the approach in the [question you linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809771/how-to-set-nothing-on-el-or-tagname-to-work-with-jquery-ui-accordion?rq=1) is still the best solution. I admit that I'm a little biased though.